# Can network monitoring tools be used to detect keyloggers?

Tags: security, keylogger

I realize that keyloggers (I am thinking malware that is trying to be as insidious as possible) use various methods to send logged keystrokes elsewhere. If for example I attempted to use a tool like MS Network Monitor and somehow could see the data being sent externally and I typed "foobar" it would naive to expect to see that exact string show up in this data: it could easily be encrypted to hide the nature of what was being sent.

However, it seems to me that such keyloggers would send *something* periodically. So if I had the machine in a quiescent state, watching the MS Network Monitor with nothing else running and then suddenly typed even a single character would I then expect activity to suddenly occur in the Monitor?

Now, even a "quiet" machine connected to the network is doing something all the time so the Monitor seems never to be quiet. Is there a way to segregate what is happening normally with what a keylogger might do?

Or is this entire approach wrong?

Comment: With all due respect, random person @thang, your response was not particularly helpful. Or respectful. I have submitted plenty of questions in this manner without the "yap yap yap" comment.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs to http://security.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, network monitoring tools can be used to detect a keylogger assuming the following:

- The keylogger, at some point in time will use the network you are monitoring.
- You can come up with a scheme that can differentiate the keylogger data from other data.

> So if I had the machine in a quiescent state, watching the MS Network Monitor with nothing else running and then suddenly typed even a single character would I then expect activity to suddenly occur in the Monitor?

That rarely be the case. Usually, the logs will be buffered and a threshold set for the data is burst to the hackers server.